# conditionally select from different tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables storing materials:

```
Table ProductsA

 ID | Description   | Date
 -----------------------------
 1  | Apple Iphone  | 01.03.2019

 Table ProductsB

 ID | Description     | Date
 -------------------------------
 1  | Apple Iphone    | 20.03.2019
 2  | Samsung Galaxy  | 20.03.2019
 3  | Dell Laptop     | 20.03.2019
```

I want to return results from ProductsB if a first query to ProductsA does not return anything. For instance, I want to return the products with date greater than 05.03.2019.

I tried:

```
SELECT COALESCE(A.ID, B.ID) as ID,
       COALESCE(A.Description, B.Description) as Description
FROM ProductsA  as A
INNER JOIN ProductsB as B on B.ID = A.ID
WHERE A.Date >= 05.03.2019
```

But it's not really working. If A return null values, then there's nothing to join. How could I achieve it?

EDIT: I would expect to return values from ProductsA, and from ProductsB if and only if nothing was found from ProductsA. Following the same reasoning, I would expect this result (querying for products with date later than 05.03.2019):

```
ID | Description     | Date
-------------------------------
1  | Apple Iphone    | 20.03.2019
2  | Samsung Galaxy  | 20.03.2019
3  | Dell Laptop     | 20.03.2019
```

Edit2: However, for results with date Greater than equal 01.03.2019, I should return only:

```
ID | Description   | Date
 -----------------------------
1  | Apple Iphone  | 01.03.2019
```

Comment: If the single row in ProductsA has a date of 6th March 2019, should you get that one row only, or one row from ProductsA and two rows from ProductsB?

Comment: Add some more sample table data, and also specify the expected result. (Keep as nicely formatted text, just as it is now!)

Comment: Thanks, I just specified

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: It's SAP HANA, but any SQL-92 solution would do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UNION like this:

```
SELECT A.ID,
       A.Description
FROM ProductsA AS A
WHERE A.Date >= '2019.03.05'

UNION ALL

SELECT B.ID,
       B.Description
FROM ProductsB AS B
WHERE B.Date >= '2019.03.05'
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM ProductsA AS A2 WHERE A2.Date >= '2019.03.05' );
```

Comment: @Cid I had used the same table alias (A) twice. It did not affect the output, but I have now anyway changed one of the table aliases to A2 to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Morten you don't even need an alias for ProductsA in the last subquery

Comment: ```union all``` will combine both results, which It's not what I want. I want to return from ProductsA, and only if nothing  is returned, then I want to query from ProductsB

Comment: @MarcoHernández This should take care of that. The part AND NOT EXISTS makes sure that you only get records from ProductsB when there is nothing returned in the first SELECT.

Comment: @Morten: Thank you! I considered UNION but didn't know that I could combine it with that last predicte NOT EXISTS.

Comment: @MarcoHernández You are welcome. If you find my answer useful, you can select it as the solution to your question.